# I have a question about this code that compares sets of numbers

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment and I'm 99.9% complete. I have one problem I can't figure out how to fix. The program compares two sets of numbers and returns the sets that are common between the two sets. The program functions as it should save, when a list of numbers has a `0` it won't return the `0` in number sets that contain a zero. it just returns the other two numbers, e.g. `103` and `031` would return `13` and `31`.

```
function compareLists(list1, list2) {

  let matches = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {

      let num1Sorted = list1[i].toString().split('').sort().join('');
      let num2Sorted = list2[j].toString().split('').sort().join('');
   
      if(num1Sorted === num2Sorted) {
        matches.push([list1[i], list2[j]]); 
      }
    }
  }

  return matches;
}

// Get input and find matches
function findMatches() {

  let list1 = document.getElementById("list1").value.split(","); 
  let list2 = document.getElementById("list2").value.split(",");
  
  list1 = list1.map(n => parseInt(n));
  list2 = list2.map(n => parseInt(n));
  
  let matches = compareLists(list1, list2);

  displayMatches(matches);  
}

// Display matches
function displayMatches(matches) {

  let container = document.getElementById("matches");
  
  if(matches.length > 0) {
  
    container.innerHTML = "";

    matches.forEach(match => {
      container.innerHTML += match[0] + "<br>" + match[1] + "<br><br>";
    });

  } else {

    container.innerHTML = "No matches found";
  
  }

}
```

I walked through the code and didn't see what I could do to fix this issue, why I'm asking for help.

Comment: There is no `0` in `031`. Try `console.log(parseInt("031"))`

Comment: if you want to find compare 2 sets of numbers and return those that are common to each just use filter and includes.  `const commonNumbers = array1.filter(x => array2.includes(x));`

Comment: @Barmar I don't think the dupe applies. OP is trying to find intersection between the *digits* of numbers and expects that `parseInt("031")` share three digits with `parseInt("103")`. Which is not the case because `31` and `103` only share two digits.

Comment: @VLAZ I've reopened, but I don't see where the description says anything about digits. It says "two sets of numbers"

Comment: Update your question to include a snippet with an HTML form with inputs with provided values and specify what the output should be.

Comment: @Barmar it's what the code does with `list1[i].toString().split('').sort().join('');` - grabs two numbers, sorts their digits, tries to check if the sorted digits are the same. Each list is turned a list of numbers with `list1.map(n => parseInt(n));` so any number that would have started with a zero wouldn't start with a zero.

Comment: If you need to compare digits without respect to order, and want leading zeroes to be kept, don't call `parseInt()`. Keep the input as strings.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question instead of just stating that you have one. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the digits in two lists, you will have to fisr find the shortest list. If they are the same length, just default to the first one.

Make copies of the lists, before computing the shortest and longest. You do not want to mutate the incoming lists.

Now that you have the shortest and longest lists, loop over the shortest and find the first index of the corresponding value in the longest. If a match is found, add it to the result and splice the value by its index in the longest list.

```js
const form = document.forms['list-compare-form'];
const container = document.querySelector('#matches');
const listSeparator = /\s*,\s*/g;

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const list1 = parseNumberList(e.target.elements['first'].value);
  const list2 = parseNumberList(e.target.elements['second'].value);
  container.innerHTML = displayMatches(compareLists(list1, list2));
}

function compareLists(list1, list2) {
  const result = [];
  const left = [...list1];
  const right = [...list2];
  const shortest = right.length < left.length ? right : left;
  const longest = shortest === left ? right : left;
  for (let shortIndex = 0; shortIndex < shortest.length; shortIndex++) {
    const value = shortest[shortIndex];
    const longIndex = longest.indexOf(value);
    if (longIndex !== -1) {
      const leftIndex = shortest === left ? shortIndex : longIndex;
      const rightIndex = leftIndex === shortIndex ? longIndex : shortIndex;
      result.push({ value, leftIndex, rightIndex });
      longest.splice(longIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function displayMatches(matches) {
  if (matches.length === 0) {
    return 'No matches found';
  }
  
  return `
    <ul>
      ${matches.map(match => `
        <li>${JSON.stringify(match)}</li>
      `).join('')}
    </ul>
  `;
}

function parseNumberList(rawInput) {
  return rawInput.trim().split(listSeparator).map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

form[name="list-compare-form"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

form label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

form label:after {
  content: ':';
}

form > button[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

li {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<form name="list-compare-form">
  <label>List #1</label>
  <input type="text" id="list-1" name="first" value="1,0,3" />
  <label>List #2</label>
  <input type="text" id="list-1" name="second" value="3,0,1" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr />
<strong>Matches</strong>
<div id="matches"></div>
```